# how to save GhostScript output

Tags: bash, ghostscript, coreldraw

I am creating an image on the fly using ghostscript.  How do I write the my_image.png to `/home/pi/Desktop` location.  I can get the image to print to screen, but not save the output to a location.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=- -q -r100 -g600x100 - >my_image.png
```

Comment: Just change the argument of `-sOutputFile` to point to a file rather than stdout?

Comment: Thanks I tried that earlier but was getting a `display: no decode delegate for this image format` error.  So I assumed it was not working. Reran the code and all seems fine.  Still getting `display: no decode delegate for this image format` but the image gets created.

Comment: that error message is from ImageMagick, not Ghostscript.

Comment: ok thanks for that info.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the OutputFile line to

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=/home/pi/my_image.png -q -r100 -g600x100 -
```